# How to plot markers animating from center?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show markers coming out from map center(cluster's position) to their respective latlong.

e.g. [redfin.com](http://redfin.com)

Marker animations like **DROP** and **BOUNCE** wont be useful here I suppose.

is there any way to acheive it?

Comment: that site's homepage hasn't got a map on it, can you give a URL demonstrating the actual map?

Comment: [link](http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale?src=homepage)..

click on **SEARCH FOR HOMES** in Home page

Comment: I'm guessing you could swap the marker image on mouseover to display an animated png and swap back to a static version on mouseout. The Google Maps API documentation tells you how to attach event handlers and swap marker images. First thing to do is get it working with two static images (eg. red and yellow versions of Google's standard pin marker), then develop your final static and animated pngs.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Thanks but you didn't get it I think. What I want is when user clicks on a cluster,instead of plotting markers of that cluster directly,I want to show them originating(dragging) from center to their location.Refer the link in previous comment.

Comment: Whoops! I see now. There's more than one visual effect going on there. You could try to track down the javascript from the page source though please don't try to learn too much from it - that's no way to build a web page these days.